# Theory $T$ has model isomorphic with its proper substructure. Prove that $T$ has infinite model isomorhpic with its proper substructure.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be theory such that there exist model $\mathbb{A}$ for $T$ such that $\mathbb{A}$ is isomorphic with its proper substructure. Prove that there exist infinite model for $T$ which is isomorphic with its substructure.

I have little trouble with that one. Isn't this obvious? Does not from the fact that structure is isomorphic with its proper substructure follows that it is infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this seems completely trivial: if $\mathbb{A}$ is isomorphic with one of its proper substructures, then $\mathbb{A}$ must be infinite, so $\mathbb{A}$ itself is an infinite model of $T$ which is isomorphic to one of its proper substructures.

I wonder if the problem is asking something slightly different; e.g. "Prove that there exists a *countably infinite* model of $T$ which is isomorphic with one of its proper substructures." (This is still quite easy, but not completely trivial.) Or "Prove that *for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$* there exists a model of $T$ of cardinality $\kappa$ which is isomorphic with one of its proper substructures" - this one I'd say is actually nontrivial (although still not hard).

Comment: Yeah, actually it asks that countable version. But that's not something I would have problem with.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk Do you see how to do the two generalizations I mentioned? (I'm asking because "that's not something I would have problem with" could either mean "I see how to do it" or "I understand why they would ask that question.")

Comment: I know how to do it :)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Another good problem is to take the other half of the conclusion as the hypothesis: If $T$ has an infinite model, then it has an infinite model which is isomorphic to a proper submodel (even one of every infinite cardinality). I would prove this by EM models. Your answer suggests that you have an answer in the countable case that doesn't work for the uncountable case - what do you have in mind?